# Wordpress local development with remote DB works super slow

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I'm developing a woocommerce shop. To do that I use docker on my localhost, and DB which is located on the remote server. My local machine is windows 10 home (so i use docker toolbox). To set my locl env I use docker-compose.yaml, which you can see below:

```
version: '3'

services:
  # Wordpress
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
    restart: always
    volumes: ['./:/var/www/html:delegated']
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: 'WORDPRESS_DB_NAME'
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: 'WORDPRESS_DB_USER'
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD
    networks:
      - wpsite
networks:
  wpsite:
```

The above config works, but its super slow. Does anyone know how to speed this up?

Comment: Hi interesting, perhaps enable network compression on the database connection (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connection-compression-control.html)

Comment: Are you sure if DB is one to blame? I would rather think that the docker/virtualBox shared folder is causing the slowness?

Comment: @IronMan, do you have any tutorial how to conduct this on WP?

Comment: Sadly I was not able to speed the docker up, an I give up for docker and jumped to xampp. It speed by about 20-25%, not much but something. If anyone have an idea, please comment.

Comment: I'm using xampp, but it's still very slow; did you do anything to speed it up?